# Expressing integral of u^v in terms of integral of u and v

Tags: integration

How is

$$ \int {f(x)}^{g(x)} dx  $$

neatly expressed in terms of:

$$ \int f(x) dx  {,\,}  \int g(x) dx ? $$

Comment: It's (provably) not possible. You can't even do this for $f(x) = 2$ (constant function) and $g(x) = x^{2}.$

Comment: Why Is it not a pity ?

Comment: See the similar question on integral of a product: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50671

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, it is a pity. Bad behavior under most non-linear operations is the reason why integrals are hard to calculate.

Comment: As for why, here's a proof for $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x$: [How to determine with certainty that a function has no elementary antiderivative?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative) It's way past elementary calculus level, however.

Answer (score 3):

There is no neat expression.  Compare
$$
\int (1-x^2) \;dx = x-\frac{x^3}{3}+C
\\
\int \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx = -\frac{x}{2}+C
$$
with
$$
\int (1-x^2)^{-1/2}\;dx = \arcsin x +C
$$

Comment: So it is impossible to generate the arcsin infinite series using $-x/2, x -x^3/3$, right?